# how can I solve below issue from visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot]

I'm seeing the above issue in visual studio code where one line is placed on another also spaces are customized. I'm not able to understand what has gone wrong. can anyone help? and it would be lot more helpful if I could do reset all settings of visual studio code as a present when installed the first time. I'm using the ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you or your theme might have set a lineHeight value which is not correct for your font/size

Open settings.json and add this line.

```
"editor.lineHeight": 0,
```

To open settings.json open the command palette Ctrl+Shift+P and then select Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

Comment: Thank you very much.. much appreciated. you guys are awesome.. working now